# How to bind services with Ninject Conventions

Tags: dependency-injection, ninject, conventions, ninject-extensions

I have two scenarios here that I want to solve with Ninject.Extensions.Conventions.

The **first** is a simple one: Whenever an instance from a namespace containing the word "service" is requested, return a singleton instance of the only matching class. I tried like so:

```
Kernel.Bind(service => service.FromThisAssembly()
                              .Select(theClass => theClass.Namespace.Contains("Service"))
                              .BindDefaultInterface()
                              .Configure(binding => binding.InSingletonScope()));
```

Some of those services get resolved, but I run into an `ActivationException` when the resolution chain reaches a point where `Impl1` has a dependency of `IService2`.

What could be wrong with this binding?

---

The **second** one is probably equally simple. All classes that inherit `BaseClass` should be instantiated via a method. This is the resolution code I used up to now, to do that per class:

```
Bind<MyViewModel>().ToMethod(ctx => fac.CreateProxy<MyViewModel>())
                   .InSingletonScope();
```

[ **Note:** In this case, fac is a custom factory that builds Castle proxies.]

How can I do such a thing for a classes inheriting from, say, `ViewModelBase` with `Extensions.Conventions`?

I figured out the select part already, here it is.

```
Kernel.Bind(ViewModel => ViewModel.FromThisAssembly()
                                  .Select(t => t.BaseType == typeof(ViewModelBase))
                                  );
```

Now I need to get that factory into action...

---

**General Questions:**

1. The binding approach of Extensions.Conventions seems to be the exact reverse of the regular way:

   - Ninject : `Bind <Interface>() . To <Implementation> ()`
   - Conventions : `SelectAllClasses().BindDefaultInterface()`

     Why is that so, or a I misunderstanding this?
2. I used to put my bindings in a class derived from NinjectModule, and I'd preferrably continue to do so. Any reasons for not doing so when working with `Extensions.Conventions`?

Comment: About your first example can you post a sample how do you try to resolve the types form the service namesapces?

Comment: There is a sample there, the first code snippet

Comment: no that is the registration part, I'm interested in how you are using/resolving the regsitered types so you get an `ActivationException`

Comment: Ah, OK. I'll add that part to the post

Comment: I updated the post, the problem is a bit different than I thought...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**first**:
Please post the exact ActivationException message + Stacktrace.
Most likely the binding for `IService2` is missing or there is a circular dependency.

**second**:
Use a binding generator:

```
    public override void Load()
    {
        this.Bind(x => x
            .FromThisAssembly()
            .SelectAllClasses()
            .InheritedFrom<BaseClass>()
            .BindWith<ToSelfProxyBindingGenerator>()
            .Configure(binding => binding.InSingletonScope()));
    }

    public class ToSelfProxyBindingGenerator : IBindingGenerator
    {
        public IEnumerable<IBindingWhenInNamedWithOrOnSyntax<object>> CreateBindings(Type type, IBindingRoot bindingRoot)
        {
            yield return bindingRoot
                .Bind(type)
                .ToMethod(ctx => fac.CreateProxy(type));
        }
    }
```

Also note that the singleton scope can be defined by the `IBindingGenerator` or @ convention using the `.Configure(..)` method.

**General Questions**:

1. You are correct, but i can't tell you the exact reasoning behind it.
2. No it is perfectly fine to put conventions into different modules. We are doing this too and it works out perfectly.

Comment: Thanks for this response. First, thanks for the sample code - it works fine. Still, I sometimes need to call `fac.CreateProxy(type)` with additional arguments. How can I pass those in? A bit against the convention thinking, ain't I?

Comment: The additional parameters which depend on a specific type are certainly out of the convention scope. Depending on cost, you may choose to filter these out and bind them individually, or you might adapt the BindingGenerator to find out what the parameters are and pass them. Is there a way to generically identify the parameters (by reflection,...) and how would you get the values of the parameters (probably by dependency injection?)? You might want to take a look at https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.factory and see how parameter identification and resolving is done there.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your code and explanations helped me a lot!